# Hi I’ve got a 2013 insignia 2.0CDTI coolant problems

Tags: coolant, sensor, opel, insignia

Coolant warning message keeps coming up on dash checked level ok replaced sensor but message keeps coming up help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It could very well be the coolant level sensor. This could be either the sensor itself or the wiring going to it.

Comment: Have you checked the coolant level, and is the system properly bled?